# Composer - multiple repositories from one project

Tags: php, composer-php

when I want to install some library by composer, it's enough to write:

```
composer require vendor/library
```

and composer downloads it from github. It's not necessary to give url for every "vendor/library" to composer.json. Composer does it "internally". But when I'd like to add some library from e.g. bitbucket, I have to create this composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo1": "dev-master",
        "vendor/my-private-repo2": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo1.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo2.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to specify an url of every library I want to install, even if they are from the same project. Is there any way to make it shorter? Can I do something like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo1": "dev-master",
        "vendor/my-private-repo2": "dev-master",
        "vendor/my-private-repo3": "dev-master",
        "vendor/my-private-repo4": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I hope my question is understandable. Thank you.

Comment: Nope, I'm just starting to learn composer, so I'm asking according to composer's manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to specify each repository separately, or manage your composer packages with [satis](https://github.com/composer/satis) or [toran proxy](https://toranproxy.com/). You'll still need to define your repositories, but only once (in satis or toran).

Comment: It looks like correct solution. Satis looks good enough. I'll try and if it'll work, I'll check the correct answer. Thanks.